# Combine different instances of the same class

Tags: haskell

I'm writing a simple CLI application which allows users to modify some documents, the real thing is more complex, but let's say I have a state which tracks the current documents and applys the actions specified on the CLI to all of them:

```
data MyState = MyState { doc :: [Document] }

run :: UserAction -> State MyState ()
run a = do s <- get ; put $ s { doc = map (edit a) (doc s) }
```

I have some functions to modify the `Document`, which is currently just an in-memory data structure:

```
data Document = Document [Stuff] [OtherStuff]
edit :: Document -> UserAction -> Document
```

Now I want to refactor this, pulling out the common interface into a class:

```
class Document d where edit :: d -> UserAction -> d
instance Document MemoryDocument where edit = ... -- as before
instance Document RemoteDocument where edit = ... -- use HDBC etc
```

But how can I integrate this easily?

The obvious change has the problem that I can't handle different types of documents in one state:

```
data (Document a) => MyState a = MyState { doc :: [a] }
```

Since `a` here would need to be a dynamic type, either MemoryDocument or RemoteDocument. I could emulate this with a wrapper type, but this is a lot of unnecessary boilerplate code (i.e. one pattern per class function per instance)

```
data MyState = MyState { doc :: [DocumentWrapper] }
data DocumentWrapper = MD MemoryDocument | RD RemoteDocument

import Control.Applicative
instance Document DocumentWrapper where
  edit (MD d) = MD <$> edit d
  edit (RD d) = RD <$> edit d
```

Is there a way to avoid this, maybe with RankNTypes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well honestly if all you have is two types then

```
 [Either MemoryDocument RemoteDocument]
```

is absolutely the way to go. In fact, if you have a static number of documents wrapping this in a sum-type is probably the right move.

What you're describing are called existential types, where you erase type information in order to store heterogenous data in one list. You could do this like

```
 {-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}
 data DocBox = forall a. Document a => DocBox a
```

Then you have a `[DocBox]` and you just use it as you would. It'll be helpful to define

```
 instance Document DocBox where
   edit (DocBox d) a = DocBox $ edit d a
```

but this is usually considered bad practice because frankly it's overkill. You have two types, use an either :) it's what it's for.

Comment: In fact, if you follow this advice, you might as well just define `instance (Document a, Document b) => Document (Either a b)`, which should help reduce boilerplate. It would even (in kind of an ugly way) allow you to nest them, like `Either a (Either b (Either c d))`, without having to define more instances for each additional type you add.